# BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT in Jenkins

Tags: java, regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

I am trying to fetch an excerpt from the Jenkins Console using the Email-ext plugin.  Although I tried using the ${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="...", end="..."} but all I got was a blank email.  Below is the log from the Jenkins Console:

```
Notify: Transaction "Transaction 2" started.    [MsgId: MMSG-16999]
t=00027899ms: Step Coded line #17: Click on About Us link started    [MsgId: MMSG-205180]   [MsgId: MMSG-205180]
t=00054300ms: Error -205177: Step Coded line #17: Click on About Us link failed - Target object was not found. Identification Method: Descriptors       Snapshot Info [MSH 1 0]    [MsgId: MERR-205177] [MsgId: MERR-205177]
```

I tried the below line in the Default Content Section of the "Editable Email Notification"

```
${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="^Error", end="found$"}
```

PS: Kindly guide me on how to write a proper RegEx to achieve the result.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Yes!

Comment: Please try once without anchors i.e. `${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start="Error", end="found"}` and please do let me know if it helped?

Comment: @Mandy8055 Tried doing without anchors, the result remains the same.

Comment: I think you should try with `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` once.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Tried with `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` & it worked.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `BUILD_LOG_REGEX` in order to get your desired solution.

```
${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex="Error.*found"}
```

#### Regex Demo

Comment: Yup, used the same solution and it worked.  Thank you once again!

Comment: I'm glad I could help =)